# Create PDF from a PNG image Or Java Panel

Tags: java, image, pdf, pdf-generation

I'm looking for a Java library that will can take a Image (PNG) and create a  PDF.
Or Create the PDF directly from a java panel that has been drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using Gnostice PDFOne for Java (http://www.gnostice.com/PDFOne_Java.asp).

Find below the code snippet that creates a PDF document from a PNG image.

```
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();

// Read the image as BufferedImage object
BufferedImage bufImg = ImageIO.read(new File(
    "SampleImage.PNG"));

// Create PdfImage object using the above BufferedImage object
PdfImage img = PdfImage.create(bufImg);

// Create a PdfPage of image size (image width x image Height)
PdfPage page1 = new PdfPage(img.width(), img.height());

// draw the image at 0, 0
page1.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

// add the page to the document object
doc.add(page1);

// save the document to the output file
doc.save("PNGImageToPDF.pdf");
doc.close();
```

To create a BufferedImage from a JPanel you can use the below code snippet.

```
int w = jpanel.getWidth();
int h = jpanel.getHeight();
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(w, h,
    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();
jpanel.paint(g2);
g2.dispose();
```

After creating BuffereImage from JPanel you can use the first code snippet to create PDF.

I hope you will find this useful.

Disclaimer: I work for Gnostice.

Answer (score 1):

Try [xsPDF](http://code.google.com/p/xspdf/):

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(imageFileName));
int width = image.getWidth(), height = image.getHeight();
XSPDF.getInstance()
.setPageSize(width, height)
.setPageMargin(NO_MARGIN)
.setImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, 0)
.createPdf(pdfFileName);
```

Comment: Its giving me the error 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Even though the file is there.
I tried to give some other name of file which does not exists
Then it gives this error

javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)

Comment: Please check if the file really exists: File file = new File(yourFilename); if (file.exists()) {/* your error output */} else {/* your XSPDF-Statements from above */} I'm quite sure the file is not accessable. If it is, please upload the image file so I can test it.