# Java: Create PDF pages from images using PDFBox 1 library

Tags: java, pdf, java-7, pdfbox

I need to convert images (mainly JPEG) directly to PDF pages for a PDF document.
It may be that the images differ in size.

Each PDF page should have the exact dimensions as the images.
So each page only contains the image in full resolution.

How can this be achieved, that a page is set to the dimensions of the image/content?
Because I saw PDF files with different page sizes and orientations but how can this be done with PDFBox?

Comment: maybe this can give you an idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466569/create-pdf-from-a-png-image-or-java-panel

Comment: well, it is not PDFBox and I think we have to create the page before the image in PDFBox, also Gnostice PDFOne is not opensource or free

Comment: ok, not PDFBox but with PDFBox you can also make buffered images, that's why I said "give you an idea", let me see if I can make something

Comment: right, should I use PDPage(PDRectangle size) and use the actual image dimensions? is this the right/best solution?

Comment: yes, that's what I was trying to say C: just didn't found the words

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Note (comment by [Valentin Waeselynck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2875803/valentin-waeselynck): as of **PDFBox 2+**, you would now use `PDImageXObject.createFromFile` or `PDImageXObject.createFromFile` or `JPEGFactory.createFromStream`. Note that `LosslessFactory.createFromImage` would be much less space-efficient. See: https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/migration.html#working-with-images

**Solution for PDFBox 1**:

I have solved this with the following code:

```
PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(someImage);
BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(in);
float width = bimg.getWidth();
float height = bimg.getHeight();
PDPage page = new PDPage(new PDRectangle(width, height));
document.addPage(page); 
PDXObjectImage img = new PDJpeg(document, new FileInputStream(someImage));
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
contentStream.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
contentStream.close();
in.close();

document.save("test.pdf");
document.close();
```

For completeness the code from the current PDFBox examples for PDFBox 2+ API (https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/AddImageToPDF.java)

```
/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 * contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 * this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 * The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 * (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 * the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package org.apache.pdfbox.examples.pdmodel;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream.AppendMode;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject;

/**
 * This is an example that creates a reads a document and adds an image to it..
 *
 * The example is taken from the pdf file format specification.
 *
 * @author Ben Litchfield
 */
public class AddImageToPDF
{
    /**
     * Add an image to an existing PDF document.
     *
     * @param inputFile The input PDF to add the image to.
     * @param imagePath The filename of the image to put in the PDF.
     * @param outputFile The file to write to the pdf to.
     *
     * @throws IOException If there is an error writing the data.
     */
    public void createPDFFromImage( String inputFile, String imagePath, String outputFile )
            throws IOException
    {
        try (PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File(inputFile)))
        {
            //we will add the image to the first page.
            PDPage page = doc.getPage(0);

            // createFromFile is the easiest way with an image file
            // if you already have the image in a BufferedImage, 
            // call LosslessFactory.createFromImage() instead
            PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile(imagePath, doc);

            try (PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, AppendMode.APPEND, true, true))
            {
                // contentStream.drawImage(ximage, 20, 20 );
                // better method inspired by http://stackoverflow.com/a/22318681/535646
                // reduce this value if the image is too large
                float scale = 1f;
                contentStream.drawImage(pdImage, 20, 20, pdImage.getWidth() * scale, pdImage.getHeight() * scale);
            }
            doc.save(outputFile);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This will load a PDF document and add a single image on it.
     * <br>
     * see usage() for commandline
     *
     * @param args Command line arguments.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        AddImageToPDF app = new AddImageToPDF();
        if( args.length != 3 )
        {
            app.usage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.createPDFFromImage( args[0], args[1], args[2] );
        }
    }

    /**
     * This will print out a message telling how to use this example.
     */
    private void usage()
    {
        System.err.println( "usage: " + this.getClass().getName() + " <input-pdf> <image> <output-pdf>" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Similar case in PDFBox examples: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/AddImageToPDF.java

It uses newer PDFBox 2+ API

Comment: You commented on a 6 year old answer / solution. Things may have changed in the last major versions of the library. Also a simple "this isn't working" is not really helpful.

Comment: Note: as of PDFBox 2+, you would now use PDImageXObject.createFromFile or PDImageXObject.createFromFile or JPEGFactory.createFromStream. Note that LosslessFactory.createFromImage would be much less space-efficient. See: https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/migration.html#working-with-images

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I have updated the question title to reflect that it is about PDFBox 1 and I will add a section with the links and link you there.