# Generate flat PDF

Tags: java, pdf-generation, xsl-fo

I currently generate complex `pdf` using `xsl-fo`.
Is it possible to create `pdf` that contains binary image of its content?

I want to basically render document inside transformation.

Maybe there are some rendering options?

My `xsl` is pretty complex, so I want to minimize changes.

Comment: Why do you want a binary image of the original PDF? Is it to stop copying or what?

Comment: Problem I have is that generated `pdf` is sent to third party and they have trouble reading it. Unfortunately I don't have much details on what exactly problem is. Only thing I know they have some unspecified problems with fonts. I thought if I can produce `pdf` that doesn't contains any fonts my problem will be solved. It is workaround, but I willing to give it a shot.

Comment: Your lack of detail in the real issue ... is the issue. Stating "they have trouble reading it" does not help. With their eyes? With a computer program that reads the content? Those two different things are very different and your idea would not solve one of them and likely make it worse. You need to provide specifics behing their issues for anyone to help you in any way that could solve the problem.

Comment: I don't want to solve specific problems with fonts, because I don't know any details on what exactly problem is. I want to avoid it completely by turning my pdf in basically picture. I still need it to be in pdf format though.

Comment: I don't think you can solve that with xsl. But since you are using java, take a look at https://pdfbox.apache.org/. 
A good start would be these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21071761/3710053 
and https://stackoverflow.com/a/23409518/3710053